# Circle Preloader in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, preloader

I have been wanting to make a circular preloader in my iPhone app, but have been struggling where to get started. I was using Sequel Pro today and saw that they had exactly what I wanted and it's open source, so I downloaded the source and couldn't find anything.

I am just looking for a start on how to make something along the lines of:

[alt text http://www.grabup.com/uploads/c7b2d101cd9caf0d927c2fa8a7850ba2.png](http://flashden.net/item/circle-preloader-with-numbers-inside/565)

or

[alt text http://www.grabup.com/uploads/fc8520a4425331a3a6a0cbf6508b510f.png](http://www.grabup.com/uploads/fc8520a4425331a3a6a0cbf6508b510f.png)

I found some flash tutorials, but it's hard to translate that into usable code in Objective-C.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not be hard to create a UIView subclass for this purpose. In the subclass you would want to do roughly the following in the `drawRect` routine:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat      center_x = self.frame.size.width / 2;
CGFloat      center_y = self.frame.size.height / 2;
double       progress = 0.42; // A floating-point number from 0..1 inclusively

// draw the frame
CGContextAddArc(context,
                center_x,
                center_y,
                std::min(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height),
                0,
                M_PI * 2,
                1 /*clockwise*/);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// draw the progress indicator
CGContextAddArc(context,
                center_x,
                center_y,
                std::min(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height),
                0,
                M_PI * 2 * progress,
                1 /*clockwise*/);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Comment: Minor point: those CGPoint variables should be declared as CGFloat.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the AnimatedGif library, and download an animated GIF from preloaders.net or something.

Just do it programatically (without IB). It's very simple. Here's the code:

```
AnimatedGif *animatedGif = [[[AnimatedGif alloc] init] autorelease];    
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"circle-loader" ofType:@"gif"]]; 
[animatedGif decodeGIF: data];
self.loadingImage = [animatedGif getAnimation]; //self.loadingImage is a UIImageView
[self.view addSubview:loadingImage];
```

Then, later when you want to remove the GIF:

```
[loadingImage removeFromSuperview];
[loadingImage release];
```

Answer (score 1):

The AnimatedGif(referenced above) Library works really well.  Had to dig to find it here: http://blog.stijnspijker.nl/2009/07/animated-and-transparent-gifs-for-iphone-made-easy/

Answer (score 0):

You mean a progress indicator, such as the one included in Interface Builder, but circular?  I assume there's a default one in the Flex framework that you've seen the tutorials for.

I think you'll have to make this on your own.  What you could do is have a view that listens for notifications of progress from an object.  When it receives these, you would calculate the  image to display and call the viewNeedsDisplay method.

I took a quick glance at the Sequel Pro source, and I think what you're looking for is the NSProgressIndicator.  But Sequel Pro is a desktop app and has more flexibility than the iPhone.  The Cocoa Touch equivalent would be UIActivityIndicatorView, which is always indeterminate (i.e., you can't specify percent completed).

Edit: yes, see fbrereton's code above for drawing routine.

And here's how you'd listen for notifications to get that progress floating-point value:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(receivedProgress:)
                                                 name:@"MyProgressIndication" 
                                               object:nil];
```

You'd post them from the object that's doing the work like this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyProgressIndication"
                                                        object:[NSNumber numberFromFloat:progress]];
```

A constant for the notification name would be best.